# Xamarin iOS App not launching unless tapped

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I used to be able to run my Xamarin iOS applications fine on my device, but when I updated it to 11.0.2, it stopped launching normally.

When trying to run the app, it gets stuck at "Launching App". Unless I tap on the app, the app doesn't run on the device.

I also noticed some issues with debugging. If I tap the app to open it, even though I can put breakpoints and step thorough, my breakpoints don't pause the app.

For example, if i set a beakpoint in some code on the loading screen, I can initially see the values of some variables, but the app does not pause and eventually the loading screen goes switches to the login page. Since the debugger and the app are not at the same point in the code, the app crashes.

I'm not sure if this is related to the code I've been adding as well. I've been implementing iOS FireBase notifications from [this documentation](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/firebaseioscloudmessaging).

What can I try to make the app launch properly?

Comment: Debug break point not launching means you have issue in debug process. try to delete bin and obj folder and then run the app... after that tell what you getting

Comment: 1.Update xamarin and your device to the newest version.  Keep them same. 2. Try as @ShiwankaChathuranga mentioned.

Comment: I deleted the bin and object folders in the iOS PCL, and made sure that Xamarin and my iPhone are up to date. My issue was not fixed. I still had to tap the app to open it and even though I can put breakpoints which are getting hit, they are not pausing the app on the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating Xamarin on the Mac, as well as other components of Visual Studio for Mac, the app launched as normal and debugging also returned to normal.

Comment: The is due to xCode is not compatible with Xamarin version. Even though the app is installed on the device, it doesn't launch the app and not able to debug.